# How to add a constructor argument to Symfony Service

Tags: php, symfony, service, symfony-3.3

I create a service that uses FilesystemCache, I don't want to make a new FilesystemCache each time I call the service so I have an argument in the service constructor where I can *give* an instance. 
What I have so far:

**Service class**:

```
class MyService
{

    private $cache;

    private $url;

    /**
     * MyService constructor.
     * @param FilesystemCache $cache
     */
    public function __construct(FilesystemCache $cache)
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }

    private function data()
    {
        if ($this->cache->has('data')) {
            $data = $this->cache->get('data');
        } else {
            $data = file_get_contents("my/url/to/data");
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

**Config**:

```
services:
  # Aliases
  Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter: '@cache.adapter.filesystem'

  # Services
  services.myservice:
    class: AppBundle\Services\MyService
    arguments:
      - '@cache.adapter.filesystem'
```

Where I use the Service:

```
$myService = $this->container->get('services.myservice');
```

But what I get is an error:

```
The definition "services.myservice" has a reference to an abstract definition "cache.adapter.filesystem". Abstract definitions cannot be the target of references.
```

So, my question is how I have to modify my service or my declaration, or whatever, to be able to do what I want to do: not create an instance each time I call the service.

Comment: I would expect your argument to be: `Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter` not the aliased service `@cache.adapter.filesystem`. Could that be it?

Comment: Well as far as I see you should make a new FilesystemCache because it's an abstract class, unless you extend this class then use the child class in the constructor

Comment: @dbrumann If I replace the alias with the route I have the next error: `has a dependency on a non-existent service "\Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter".`

Comment: @YamenNassif FilesystemCache is not an abstract class https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FilesystemCache.php

Comment: @piterio sorry its my bad, did you add it to the AppKernel.php ?
try new Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter(),

Comment: @YamenNassif yes. If I use `new Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter()`, or `new Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache()` I have this message: `__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache, string given`

Comment: well this is as far as i can help now cuz i cant test now. but, you should keep this line new Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapte() in your AppKernel. And try to play around your service arguments till its fixed.

Comment: @YamenNassif I found a solution. I will answer my own question. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommand you to use the `cache.app` service instead of your own `filesystem.cache`. Also, you could create your own Adapter.

Comment: If I replace my @filesystem.cache with @cache.app what I get is this error: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Services\MyService::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache, instance of Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter given`

Answer (score 0):

To make that posible I had to register a new service with the class I want to use in my service constructor. So, my `services.yml` would be like:

```
services:
  filesystem.cache:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache
  services.myservice:
    class: AppBundle\Services\MyService
    arguments:
      - '@filesystem.cache'
```

and now I'm able to use my service without getting an error.

Comment: Instead of defining filesystem.cache, try just replacing the @filesystem.cache with the class name.  I would think autowire will pick it up.

Comment: @Cerad what I get: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Services\MyService::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache, string given`

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard S3.3 autowire setup, this worked for me:

```
// services.yml

// This basically gives autowire a concrete cache implementation
// No additional parameters are needed
Symfony\Component\Cache\Simple\FilesystemCache:

// And there is no need for any entry for MyService
```

....

```
// MyService.php
use Psr\SimpleCache\CacheInterface;

public function __construct(CacheInterface $cache)
```

This of course will only work if you only have one concrete implementation of CacheInterface in your container.